# Como fazer funções membro constantes em PhP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, método, const

Eu estava estudando o que meu livro chamou de "funções membros constantes" em C++. ou seja, funções que não podem alterar nenhum atributo da classe nem chamar outros métodos que não sejam constantes. Assim, eu fiz esse código **em C++.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Foo
{
     string outra_coisa;
  public: 
    void printa_algo(string algo) const;
};

int main()
{
    Foo tolo;
    string alguma_coisa = "coisa_alguma";
    tolo.printa_algo(alguma_coisa);

    return 0;
}

void Foo::printa_algo(string algo) const
{
    cout << algo;
}
```

É possível fazer o mesmo **em PHP**?

Comment: O que o título tem a ver com esse código?

Comment: Bruno dá sim com certeza, mas, realmente o titulo não condiz com a pergunta!

Comment: Vish é msm...pera ae..Arrumado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom depois de alguma pesquisa vi em um livro que não é possível, **pelo menos não é trivial**, criar funções desse tipo em PhP. Você pode criar métodos que **não fazem** alterações em atributos, mas não pode criar métodos **que não podem fazer** alterações de maneira nenhuma.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você está se referindo às funções estáticas, cujas podem ser chamadas sem criar uma instância da classe, e que não podem modificar propriedades e membros da mesma, se for isso, é só usar a palavra-chave `static`:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function Bar() {
        echo 'Olá, mundo!';
    }
}

// você pode chamar assim
Foo::Bar();

// ou assim
$classname = 'Foo';
$classname::Bar();

// mas não assim
$class = new Foo;
$class->Bar(); // erro
?>
```

Comment: Eu estou ciente sobre as funções estáticas, a pergunta era mesmo sobre métodos constantes.

Comment: Me corrija se estiver errado, mas acho que isso não existe em PHP.